# Is edge points of object represent an ellipse?

Tags: image-processing, geometry, computer-vision

Given an edge points of object. Let us say `Obj = (xi,yi); i=1,2,3,....`
How can we know if these edge points represent an ellipse or not?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have more than 2 points you could try linear fitting by using least squares:

See here:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153150/104118

See section 7 **Fitting an Ellipse to 2D Points** in the actual link: http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LeastSquaresFitting.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head, I would calculate the axis with minimal variance (call it a) and the axis with maximal variance (call it b).

I would check that those axes are reasonably close to being perpendicular - if not then it's probably not an ellipse. If they are close to being perpendicular, I would rotate the point cloud so that a and are aligned with the x- and y-axes.

Next step would be to translate the point cloud so its center is at (0,0) and then check that each translated point lie close to the perimeter of an ellipse with axes a and b by putting each of the points into the equation of the ellipse and checking that the value is close to 0.

This is all based on me reading "edge points" as just looking at the points used by edges. If the edges themselves are to be involved, you would have to check that the edges go "around the clock" as well.

Well I know this was loose... hope it made sense somehow :-).